# How to find all combination of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, powerset

I'm using node.js currently, and i would like to find / try all the unique possibilities resulting from the combinations of data stored in an array.

Example :

```
// source array
var array = [0,1,2];

// what i need :
0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000
001
002
etc, up to a configurable length.
```

I've looked on the forums and didn't manage to find something like this.

I've searched on npm and found some librairies that are doing similar things, but never all the possibilities i need. I'm feeling like my need is very similar to a bubble sorting algorithm, but i don't know how to do this.

Also it would be very much better to do it without storing the whole output in a variable at the same time, as the idea is that my code needs to work with larger arrays.

Any idea or solution i missed would help at this point !

Edit : Also, i would like to continuously try combination until i decide it's enough, such as 500 try or if the last combination length is 5 for example.

Comment: What do you have so far? How can we be of assistance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Generating all combinations of elements in a single array (in pairs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241174/javascript-generating-all-combinations-of-elements-in-a-single-array-in-pairs)

Comment: Sorry, i've posted too fast, was trying to put the tags and accidentally put enter...

I made a few tries with a foreach loop and ended up with a code very similar to a bubble sorting.

But that's just not enough because i would need to check all the possibilities of the array with some kind of limit (let's say after X combination we stop, or if the combination length is above Y).

Comment: Depending what it is you want to do with the results, you might find [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) helpful.

Comment: You're looking for some kind of recursive algorithm. Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650834/using-recursion-to-search-all-combinations-of-elements-in-an-array-of-integers

Comment: Is there a reason you don't include `012` in the results?

Comment: @scottSauyet No , i just forgot the 0xx ... 
The point is that i need absolutely every unique combination of the array, one by one , up to a result of X length.

I will edit my question to add the 0xx results, thanks for noticing, i actually managed to fail my question ...

Comment: @mbrandau Yes this seems to be very similar, except that i will work with characters too. I will investigate this post, i didn't see it when i was looking. 

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
function variations(arr, length) {
    if (length == 0)
        return [];
    else if (length == 1)
        return arr.map(e => e.toString());

    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let tail of variations(arr, length - 1))
            result.push(arr[i].toString() + tail);
    }
    return result;
}

function variations2(arr, maxLength) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxLength; i++)
        result = result.concat(variations(arr, i));
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
var array = [0,1,2];
console.log(variations2(array, 2));
```

Output:

```
["0", "1", "2", "00", "01", "02", "10", "11", "12", "20", "21", "22"]
```

Comment: Note that `permute` is probably not a good name for this, as that implies that there are n! results, and that the values are each used only once per output.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, with several reusable functions:

```js
const flatten = arrays => [].concat.apply([], arrays);
const range = (lo, hi) => [...new Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => i + lo)
const join = joiner => list => list.join(joiner)

const charSeqs = (n, chars) => (n < 1) 
    ? [[]]
    : flatten(chars.map(char => charSeqs(n - 1, chars).map(
        seq => flatten([char].concat(seq))
      )))

const allCharSeqs = (n, chars) => flatten(range(1, n).map(i => charSeqs(i, chars)))

console.log(allCharSeqs(3, [0, 1, 2]).map(join('')))
```